# Python: Altering list values from a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I am creating a simple Bin packing program in Python for a class and am having a scope issue that I cannot quite track down. I am attempting to alter the value in the ffBins list however the list the value is unaltered.

The print results show what I expect ("10 5 5") as i is subtracted from j but it is not altering the value in the actual list as I am expecting. I suspect I need to point at the list in a different way during the loop but the solution is eluding me. Is there a simple way to alter the values in the list instead of just the current j variable?

```
    ffBins.append(10)
    for i in ffItems:
        itemPacked = 0
        for j in ffBins:
            #print(j)
            if j >= i:
                print(j),
                print(i),
                j = j-i
                print(j)
                itemPacked = 1
            #break
        if itemPacked == 0:
            ffBins.append(10)
            ffBins[-1] = ffBins[-1]-ffItems[i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you're doing in this code is rebinding j to a new value. You need to set the value back in the list by its index. You can use `enumerate` to get the index as well as the value.

```
for index, j in enumerate(ffBins):
    ...
     ffbins[index] = j - i
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel... I just stepped away for a few minutes and realized my mistake. Oops.